# Is there any way to get maven project version from pom.xml in classpath dependency jar

Tags: java, spring-boot, maven, pom.xml

We have a health Utility jar, which is added as maven dependency in another project A. We want to get maven version of project A from health Utility jar. Can anybody suggest how to get it?

Comment: For what purpose?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: we have created a maven project (Health Utility) which will be added as maven dependency to other maven projects  ex project A
the requirement is to get the version of maven project A  from health Utility 

In Health Utility, we are exposing an api to get version details and health status of project A or the components which are using health utility jar

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at org.springframework.boot.SpringBootVersion, this is one way to retrieve version information for a class/package.

Answer (score 0):

Easiest for this scenario (for few properties):

"Filter" properties into a (spring-used) properties file.

*pom.xml*:

```
...
   <parent>
     <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
     <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
     <version>2.5.6</version>
     <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
   </parent>
   ...
   <version>1.2.3.SNAPSHOT</version>
...
```

This configures maven to filter all `.yaml`, `.yml` and `.properties` files from `src/main/resources/` (see [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/), [here](https://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/examples/filter.html) and [here](https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.5.6/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.5.6.pom)).

Then in
*src/main/resources/application.properties*, you would:

```
my.domain.maven.project.version=${project.version} 
# a key of your choice, but the value *has to be* 
# ${project.version} or @project.version@
```

On a build (involving `process-ressources` phase (e.g. `mvn clean process-classes`)), this will(should) be "filtered" into `${project.buildDir}`(normally target/classes)/application.properties:

```
my.domain.maven.project.version=1.2.3.SNAPSHOT
```

Which is then available like:

```java
@SpringBootApplication // @Configuration/@Component/Bean-like/@...
public class MyApp {

    @Value("${my.domain.maven.project.version}")
    private String mavenProjectVersion;
    // do something with it
}
```

---

But of course there are many different solutions/approaches, e.g.:

- [Use `build-info`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/maven-plugin/reference/htmlsingle/#goals-build-info) (spring-maven-plugin)
- [properties-maven-plugin](http://www.mojohaus.org/properties-maven-plugin/plugin-info.html) ("3rd party")
- ...